# Socket.io client initialization doesn't seem to be working as documented (4.x)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My scoket.io server is hosted on virtualized hardware exposed at an endpoint of `example.com/<id>/socket.io/`

And socket.io by default will try to connect to `example.com/socket.io/` so I need to customize the endpoint used. [According to the docs for 4.x](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#Custom-namespace):

> In the examples above, the client will connect to the main namespace.
> Using only the main namespace should be sufficient for most use cases,
> but you can specify the namespace with:
>
> ```
> // same origin version
> const socket = io("/admin");
> // cross origin version
> const socket = io("https://server-domain.com/admin");
> ```

So I went with:

```
const socket = io("/<id>/socket.io");
```

and also tried:

```
const socket = io("/<id>/socket.io/");
```

and

```
const socket = io("https://example.com/<id>/socket.io");
```

and

```
const socket = io("https://example.com/<id>/socket.io/");
```

But the failing polling messages show that it's trying to connect to the default `https://example.com/socket.io/`.

I can verify that the socket server is running at the correct endpoint because visiting `https://example.com/<id>/socket.io/` serves a message: `{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}` and `https://example.com/<id>/socket.io/socket.io.js` serves Socket.IO v4.0.0

What can I do to further debug or fix this?

Edit: Tried with v3 and experienced the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to get Socket.IO to connect to a different *path*, not a *namespace*. In short, you should use the `path` option, like so:

```js
// The string passed as the first argument is the Namespace to use,
// not the path to connect to.
const socket = io("/", {
  // Set the <id> to your actual path ID.
  path: "/<id>/socket.io/"
});
```

Read more about Socket.IO Namespaces [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/namespaces/).